# Publishing MVC project to file system using TFS build server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, msbuild, asp.net-mvc-5.2

getting below errors when trying to publish a MVC project using TFS build server to file system location. i am using MVC 5 and VS2013

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets (55): This specific WebPublishMethod(FileSystem) is not yet supported on msbuild command line.  Please use Visual Studio to publish.
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets (62): Target WebFileSystemPublish Failed

Comment: What version of TFS do you have on build agent?

Comment: we are using TFS  2013- v12

Comment: Which parameters you used in MSBuild Arguments during your pubilishing?Did you use anyone not support by MSbuild?